# How to upgrade to the Unstable Ubuntu Builds

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Is there a way to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 install to Trusty Dev without upgrading via .iso because it keeps erasing my programs and my desktop environment that I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use back in time

http://backintime.le-web.org/

back up the home directory and /etc/apt, that should do it, unless you have something stored elsewhere, all your programs are there, move the back up to an external hard drive/usb and do the upgrade using the iso, download back in time on the new system and restore.

Comment: @user238446 You're welcome :)